# Finding Min & Max of a column for each identical value in another column

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a table in an EXCEL file as follows (I can read the excel file, thats not the problem here) -

```
+------------+-------+-------------+--------+-------+
|    Date    | RefNo | MasterName  | Value  | Type  |
+------------+-------+-------------+--------+-------+
| 01-01-2020 | 45    | ABC Pty Ltd | 123.45 | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 |  2    | XYZ Ltd     | 134.5  | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 | 46    | ABC Pty Ltd | 765    | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 | 47    | ABC Pty Ltd | 465.4  | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 | 3     | XYZ Ltd     | 468    | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 | S_1   | ABC Pty Ltd | 678    | Sales |
| 01-01-2020 | S_2   | XYZ Ltd     | 68     | Sales |
+------------+-------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

I use the following query to get the total amount against each 'Master' for each day (example table has only one day of sales) -

```
var query = data.GroupBy(row => new { row.Date, row.MasterName, row.Type })
    .Select(grp => new MasterAccount
    {
        Date = grp.Key.Date,
        Name = grp.Key.MasterName,
        Type = grp.Key.Type,
        Amount = grp.Sum(c => c.Value)
        MinRef = // Get minimum ref no. (type: int)
        MaxRef = // Get maximum ref no. (type: int)
    });
```

***Note:*** As you can see, right now my code doesn't get the RefNo column when performing the 'GroupBy' cause if I do that, then it would create a new MasterAccount against each RefNo. And I dont want that.

**I want to get the MinRef and MaxRef against each master**. So in case of '*ABC Pty Ltd*' that would be *45 & 47* respectively, while ignoring the string '*S_1*'. Perhaps use TryParse to make sure that it isn't a string that cannot be converted into an int.

But I am not sure how to implement it within this code.

Comment: Did you try grp.OrderBy().First() and grp.OrderByDescending().First()? Is it OK if they are the same (only one entry)?

Comment: What should I order by? Right now my group doesnt contain the RefNo. cause if i did pull that, then it would create a new MasterAccount against each RefNo. That's not what I want.

Comment: Select into a normalized (anonymous) type with _actual_ int (or int?) values _before_ the GroupBy. Then the rest becomes trivial.. as the types are correct for Min/Max (used just like Sum above). Since this is not L2S/EF then it’s simple L2O so there is no need to separate queryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define function which converts string to int? (null when converstion is not possible)

```
    private int? StrToInt(string s)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
            return i;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

and then use it in the LINQ expression:

```
    MinRef = grp.Min(i => StrToInt(i.RefNo).GetValueOrDefault(0),
    MaxRef = grp.Max(i => StrToInt(i.RefNo).GetValueOrDefault(0)
```

Comment: I was incorrect with my thinking of this implementation. With a small change this worked beautifully. For MinRef, I assigned int.MaxValue as default and for MaxRef, I assigned -1 as default.

Comment: Reason being, 0 would become the minimum and I would get the wrong value. For MaxRef, i wanted it to be explicitly clear that no int was found, not even 0, so I assigned -1 in such cases.